# Can't build with v141_xp toolset (can't install v7.1A SDK)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2017

VS works fine when compiling with `v141` toolset and Windows 10 SDK but it breaks as soon as I switch to the `v141_xp` toolset and Windows 7.0 SDK and hit Build.
Important note: `v141_xp` toolset used to work about half a year ago. At that time I had installed on this machine all Visual Studio softwares from 2010 to 2017. Then I decided to remove all of those, except 2017. I don't know if XP toolset broke after that because I haven't used it since then.

Example output from some default project:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v141_xp\Toolset.targets(36,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSdkDir_71A variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(375,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.
1>Project1.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I remove XP support, the installer informs me that 220MB will be freed but if when I choose to reinstall it, says that "Total space required" is 507KB, which is suspiciously low.
Also, whenever I choose to install XP support, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A` gets created, but it remains empty.

Sometimes, even with XP support installed, this message gets printed 2 times when I load an XP vcxproj:

```
Project 'Project1' could not be loaded because it's missing install components. To fix this launch Visual Studio installer with the following selections:
Windows XP support for C++
```

Installing missing features won't fix it, not even reinstalling the entire VS.

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me for a while.  I'd tried reinstalling the XP build tools, repairing the VS install itself, etc.  I finally solved this by:

1. opening up the VS 2017 installer (Tools Menu -> Get Tools and Features)
2. picking the "Individual Components" tab
3. scrolling down to "Compilers, build tools, and runtimes" section
4. checking "Windows XP support for C++" (at the bottom of that section).

That magically made the SDK findable by the previously-installed _xp toolchain.